Ansible doesn't see callback_whitelist
When I add timer callback to ansible it doesn't see it. It doesn't output times for tasks
My ansible.cfg:
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
remote_user = cas12
host_key_checking = false
# callback_whitelist=cgroup_perf_recap
callback_whitelist = timer, profile_tasks, profile_roles
#callback_whitelist = timer1, mail, profile_roles
#[callback_cgroup_perf_recap]
#control_group=ansible_profile

[privilege_escalation]
become = True
become_method = sudo
become_user = root
become_ask_pass = False

[ssh_connection]
ssh-args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=120s
pipelining= True

Run:
ansible-playbook any.yaml

Expected:
Timer and profiler appear in the ansible output.
Actual:
There are no time and profile output in ansible.

could you add the output of ansible-playbook any.yaml -vvvv? and also, what version of ansible are you using? (run ansible --version)

Use the key stdout_callback to, quote:

Set the main callback used to display Ansible output.

In your case
shell> grep stdout_callback ansible.cfg
stdout_callback = ansible.posix.timer

For example, the below playbook for testing
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - wait_for:
        timeout: 3

gives
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 3 seconds

